# Having backup kernels in ubuntu

Tags: kernel, backup

I had many kernels in my Ubuntu, but recently I deleted all of them (except one) as they were corrupt. Now I am left with a single kernel onto which I log in every day. I am afraid as to what will happen if this kernel gets corrupt due to some updates - I'll be totally unable to boot due to lack of backup kernels.

Is there a way to have additional backup kernels? Can I download past kernels into some folder so that they show up when I log in?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `http://packages.ubuntu.com/` and search for `linux-image` and download the one you want and install it using `dpkg -i linux-image-<version>.deb`

Example: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-image&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

Comment: If I install an old version, will it overwrite my current fresh kernel? How do I then come back to using the newer kernel?

Answer (score 0):

I personally keep 2 working kernels at all times. When there is a kernel update, if it works, remove the oldest.

A working kernel should not become "corrupt". If you are having a problem with a kernel update you should identify your hardware and file a bug report. If a working kernel stops working, that suggests a hardware problem.